# Magento 2 - 2.1 to 2.3 update

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, magento2.3, magento-upgrade

How can I do a version update of my **Magento 2.1** version to **Magento 2.3**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First check the php version PHP 7.1 or 7.2

1- Run command :-

```
composer require magento/product-community-edition=2.3.3 --no-update
```

2- Run the composer update

```
composer update
```

And finally composer update command is done so run the below commands :-

```
rm -rf var/di/* var/generation/* var/cache/* var/log/* var/page_cache/* var/session/* var/view_preprocessed/* pub/static/*
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento setup:di:compile
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
php bin/magento cache:clean
php bin/magento cache:flush
php bin/magento indexer:reindex
```