# Magento2: Upgrade 2.0 to 2.3

Tags: magento2, magento-upgrade

I have Magento v2.0.17. I want to Upgrade Magento 2.0 to 2.3. Is it possible to upgrade direct 2.0 to 2.3?

Please let me know which Magento version stable now.

Which functionality will break in Magento website after the upgrade Magento 2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First check the php version PHP `7.1` or `7.2`

1- Run command :-

```
composer require magento/product-community-edition=2.3.3 --no-update
```

2- Run the composer update

```
composer update
```

And finally composer update command is done so run the below commands :-

```
rm -rf var/di/* var/generation/* var/cache/* var/log/* var/page_cache/* var/session/* var/view_preprocessed/* pub/static/*
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento setup:di:compile
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
php bin/magento cache:clean
php bin/magento cache:flush
php bin/magento indexer:reindex
```

And second Only third party module i think broke down because version issues and other magento 2 default not broke down.

and my answers are accepted:-

**[Magento 2 - 2.1 to 2.3 update](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/305498/magento-2-2-1-to-2-3-update/305502#305502)**

Comment: I will go through as your instruction. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I know that answear above works. But I have question about this `composer update` part. Why not just `composer update magento/product-community-edition --with-all-dependencies`?

If I understand this right, in scenario with `composer update` composer will try to upgrade ALL modules that don't have version in composer.json. Not only magento2 modules. It may cause a lot of work to check all dependencies if we have customizations for this modules.

And what about magento/quality-patches. I have patches installed with this tool and added it to composer.json at post-install-cmd to make it automatically in deploy. After magento upgrade, patches stoped to work. I had to delete all modules that have patches. Run composer install again and apply patches again. What should be correct way to work with magento/quality-patches and composer to by fully compatible with upgrades?