# composer show magento/product-community-edition --all it show all version or your satup version?

Tags: magento2

in my system it show the last my setup version 2.3.4 my question is "it show the latest version with all or show your setup version and other degrade versions"

name     : magento/product-community-edition
descrip. : eCommerce Platform for Growth (Community Edition)
keywords : 
versions : * 2.3.4, 2.3.3-p1, 2.3.3, 2.3.2-p2, 2.3.2, 2.3.1, 2.3.0, 2.2.11, 2.2.10, 2.2.9, 2.2.8, 2.2.7, 2.2.6, 2.2.5, 2.2.4, 2.2.3, 2.2.2, 2.2.1, 2.2.0, 2.2.0-rc30, 2.2.0-rc23, 2.2.0-rc22, 2.2.0-rc21, **strong text**2.2.0-rc20, 2.1.18, 2.1.17, 2.1.16, 2.1.15, 2.1.14, 2.1.13, 2.1.12, 2.1.11, 2.1.10, 2.1.9, 2.1.8, 2.1.7, 2.1.6, 2.1.5, 2.1.4, 2.1.3, 2.1.2, 2.1.1, 2.1.0, 2.1.0-rc3, 2.1.0-rc2, 2.1.0-rc1, 2.0.18, 2.0.17, 2.0.16, 2.0.15, 2.0.14, 2.0.13, 2.0.12, 2.0.11, 2.0.10, 2.0.9, 2.0.8, 2.0.7, 2.0.6, 2.0.5, 2.0.4, 2.0.3, 2.0.2, 2.0.1, 2.0.0, 0.42.0-beta7
type     : metapackage
license  : Open Software License 3.0 (OSL-3.0) (OSI approved) https://spdx.org/licenses/OSL-3.0.html#licenseText
license  : Academic Free License v3.0 (AFL-3.0) (OSI approved) https://spdx.org/licenses/AFL-3.0.html#licenseText
source   : []
dist     : [zip] https://repo.magento.com/archives/magento/product-community-edition/magento-product-community-edition-2.3.4.0.zip 
names    : magento/product-community-edition

requires
magento/magento2-base 2.3.4
php ~7.1.3||~7.2.0||~7.3.0
ext-bcmath *
ext-ctype *
ext-curl *

Please help me to clear this query !!

Comment: Your want to how to upgrade Magento 2??

Comment: yes i want to upgrade my version to 2.3.4 to 2.3.5

Comment: Magento 2.3.5 is not released yet.

Comment: @ahsan https://devdocs.magento.com/release/

Answer (score 0):

First check the php version PHP 7.1 or 7.2

1- Run command :-

`composer require magento/product-community-edition=your version --no-update`

2- Run the composer update

`composer update`

And finally composer update command is done so run the below commands :-

`rm -rf var/di/* var/generation/* var/cache/* var/log/* var/page_cache/* var/session/* var/view_preprocessed/* pub/static/*
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento setup:di:compile
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
php bin/magento cache:clean
php bin/magento cache:flush
php bin/magento indexer:reindex`

And my accpeted answer check please

**[Magento 2 - 2.1 to 2.3 update](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/305498/magento-2-2-1-to-2-3-update/305502#305502)**

Comment: Hello @Karuna Khatri It is working or not??

Comment: Hello @Karuna have try upgrade magento .Finally released magento 2.2.5.https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/release-notes/ReleaseNotes2.2.5CE.html

Answer (score 0):

Run these commands in root directory.

composer require magento/product-community-edition=2.3.5 --no-update

composer update

php bin/magento setup:upgrade

Comment: are you sure a Magento 2.3.5 version is released?

Comment: I run composer command and get error. Could not find package magento/product-community-edition in a version match  
  ing 2.3.5

Comment: Hello @KarunaKhatri not RELEASE magento 2.3.5

Comment: @mohit https://devdocs.magento.com/release/